# Cannot resolve keyword 'some_field' into field. Choices are:

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am filtering the Model by related Model but I am encountering some errors specified in the question title.

> Cannot resolve keyword 'bmodel' into field. Choices are: title,
> description, number, client_user_id, assignee_id

Models are like that:

**1st model**

```
class AModel(BaseModel):
    title = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client_user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="client_users", null=True)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="user_assignees", null=True)
```

**2nd model**

```
class BModel(models.Model):
    amodel = models.ForeignKey("AModel", related_name="a_model", on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="entity_user")
```

**my queryset**

```
class AModelView(GenericViewSet):
    queryset = AModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AmodelSerializer
      
    def get_queryset(self):
      current_user = 2
      qs = super().get_queryset()
      qs = qs.filter(a_model__user_id__in=current_user)
      return qs
```

How can I solve this issue? can anybody help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong. You are assigning `a_model` related to `BModel`

```
amodel = models.ForeignKey("AModel", related_name="a_model", on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
```

You need to change it to:

```
amodel = models.ForeignKey("AModel", related_name="bmodel", on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
```

And your query should work.

Comment: No. now int object is not iterable why i do not know

Comment: Because `__in` filter requires iterable to be passed and you are passing just an int. You need to change  query to `a_model__user_id=current_user` or make sure that `current_user` is a list.

Comment: yes I did but only one result comes  but I have more. for this what should I do?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Where do you expect to see more results? You can use `__in` filter to filter results for more users.

Comment: ok there are more results of AModel related to user which its id is 2

Comment: `qs` variable should contain all instances of `AModel` that are connected to user with ID 2 via `BModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying sthg like this. You take from the *attribute name* do not confuse with `related_name` when getting related model in `.filter()`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    current_user = 2
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    qs = qs.filter(client_user__user_id__in=current_user)
    return qs
```